# Is there a Tidy for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting, ssms

I'm looking for a tool that that I can use to clean up (formatting, tabs, etc.) my stored procedures and views.  Is there anything like [HTML Tidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy), but for SQL which is free/open source?

Comment: If you like gbn's answer, can you mark it as answwered?

Comment: Related: [Command line SQL formatter or beautifier - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/command-line-sql-formatter-or-beautifier)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options that seem to be missing, and I think are both more appropriate than most options listed so far:

- [Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter](http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx) / [poorsql.com](http://poorsql.com/) (free, open-source, SSMS add-in, command line formatter, full [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)/[DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) script formatting, and I'm the author/maintainer, so I get to put it first :))
- [T-SQL Tidy](http://tsqltidy.com.serv6.temphostspace.com/downloads.aspx) (free, SSMS Add-In, full DDL/DML script formatting, apparently an [SQL Server 2008 R2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008_R2) add-in can do offline formatting also now - but not open-source?)

I believe either of these makes more sense than any of the previous answers because the other options provided are:

- Online-only (instant SQL formatter)
- Trialware / commercial software (SQL pretty printer)
- Don't format (SSMS tools pack, the accepted answer)
- Don't handle full T-SQL properly ([CPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN) module, SQL-talk prettifier)
- Incomplete, only handle some statements (SqlFormat project)

Answer (score 4):

[ssmstools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) is useful

Comment: I just installed this and its a very useful tool kit. +1

Comment: Thanks, its shaping up to be a great tool for me.  Just a word to the wise.  This program will now work unless you have SP2 installed.

Comment: This has to be the BEST/only sql server addon i have ever used. The fact that it has tidy and snippets is GOLD!

Answer (score 1):

I use [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) occasionally. It does the job for me.

Comment: Website is free to use, but the add-in for SSMS is $40 USD.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the free Simple Talk *[Prettifier](http://www.simple-talk.com/prettifier/)*.

It's basic, but it might satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

An [SSMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) 2005/2008 addin: http://code.google.com/p/sqlformat/

It lacks some features, but it is very a good start.

Comment: The link is broken (404). [Google Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Developers#Google_Code) effectively closed in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

*[SQL::Beautify](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Beautify)* may or may not help (a [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) module).  I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The [format()](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#formatting-of-sql-statements) function in [python-sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse) works nicely for me.

You can install it with

```bash
pip install sqlparse
```

And then use it in Python like so:

```py
import sqlparse

raw = """select order_month,order_day, count(distinct order_id) as num_orders,
count(book_id) as num_books,sum(price) as total_price,sum(count(book_id))
over (partition by order_month order by order_day) as running_total_num_books
from (select date_format(co.order_date,'%y-%m') as order_month,
date_format(co.order_date,'%y-%m-%d') as order_day,co.order_id,ol.book_id,
ol.price from cust_order co inner join order_line ol on co.order_id=ol.order_id)
sub group by order_month,order_day order by order_day asc"""

tidied = sqlparse.format(raw, keyword_case='upper', reindent=True)

print(tidied)
```

Which will output

```sql
SELECT order_month,
       order_day,
       count(DISTINCT order_id) AS num_orders,
       count(book_id) AS num_books,
       sum(price) AS total_price,
       sum(count(book_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY order_month
                                 ORDER BY order_day) AS running_total_num_books
FROM
  (SELECT date_format(co.order_date, '%y-%m') AS order_month,
          date_format(co.order_date, '%y-%m-%d') AS order_day,
          co.order_id,
          ol.book_id,
          ol.price
   FROM cust_order co
   INNER JOIN order_line ol ON co.order_id=ol.order_id) sub
GROUP BY order_month,
         order_day
ORDER BY order_day ASC
```

Comment: Perhaps add some sample input and output? (But *** ***without*** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: No exactly sure how you meant this, but added example usage now.